# Is it possible to lengthen a given column based another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

This is what I want to achieve: For each child, I would like to have the mother right below him/her.

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- tribble(
  ~id, ~child, ~mother,
  1, "John", "Jane",
  1, "George", "Jane",
  2, "Matthew", "Angela",
  3, "Gwel", "Macrine",
  3, "Tim", "Macrine",
  3, "Jim", "Macrine"
)

# Desired

newdata <- tribble(
  ~id, ~child, ~mother,
  1, "John", "Jane",
  1, "George", "Jane",
  1, "Jane", NA,
  2, "Matthew", "Angela",
  2, "Angela", NA,
  3, "Gwel", "Macrine",
  3, "Tim", "Macrine",
  3, "Jim", "Macrine",
  3, "Macrine", NA
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group_modify` from the `dplyr` package to `add_row` per group.

```r
library(dplyr)

mydata |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  group_modify(~add_row(., child = unique(.$mother), mother = NA))

#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id child   mother 
#>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1     1 John    Jane   
#> 2     1 George  Jane   
#> 3     1 Jane    <NA>   
#> 4     2 Matthew Angela 
#> 5     2 Angela  <NA>   
#> 6     3 Gwel    Macrine
#> 7     3 Tim     Macrine
#> 8     3 Jim     Macrine
#> 9     3 Macrine <NA>
```

Comment: don't forget to `ungroup()`! I answered a question on here literally last week which was because the OP had grouped their dataframe and forgot/never realised

Comment: This is amazing! I will remember to ungroup!

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. Get the id and mother column, renaming the mother column to 'child'
2. Get the unique rows
3. Add it onto the end of the original dataframe
4. Order by id, then mother.

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(mydata,
          mydata |> select(id, child = mother) |> distinct()) |> 
  arrange(id, mother)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
     id child   mother 
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  
1     1 John    Jane   
2     1 George  Jane   
3     1 Jane    NA     
4     2 Matthew Angela 
5     2 Angela  NA     
6     3 Gwel    Macrine
7     3 Tim     Macrine
8     3 Jim     Macrine
9     3 Macrine NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R approach:

```
mother_data <- unique(data.frame(id = mydata$id, child = mydata$mother, mother = NA))
rbind(mydata, mother_data)[order(newdata$id),]
```

```
  id child   mother 
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  
1     1 John    Jane   
2     1 George  Jane   
3     1 Jane    NA     
4     2 Matthew Angela 
5     2 Angela  NA     
6     3 Gwel    Macrine
7     3 Tim     Macrine
8     3 Jim     Macrine
9     3 Macrine NA
```